# Cursor completed without all values fetched

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

The script processes the SQL Server database backup one by one (through a cursor) and on completion of all the database it sends a [success] mail.

Cursor code:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE Name NOT IN ('Master', 'tempdb') 
ORDER BY Name
```

Result: 20 databases

The script everyday sends a success mail on completion of all the 20 databases.
Today, I got success mail with completion of only 9 databases (but there are still 20 databases in my SQL Server).

What exactly happened? Why cursor completed with only 9 DBs?

Script Logic:

```
IF (@BackupType = 'Differential' OR @BackupType = 'Trxlog')
BEGIN
    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT Name 
        FROM sys.databases 
        WHERE Name NOT IN ('Master', 'tempdb') 
        ORDER BY Name
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT Name 
        FROM sys.databases 
        WHERE Name NOT IN ('tempdb') 
        ORDER BY Name
END 

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @DBName  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   
        --Code for taking the backup                
        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @DBName   
END

--Code for sending the [Success] mail
--

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it  every time . ? if not only next steps i think will  be to log output  of each statement to file or table

Comment: Do you use proper booleans to check for the success/failure? Though like the TheGameisWar said, I'd check for consistencies both in your list and on the execution (or failure thereof) of the script.

Comment: Actually, your code example is wrong. Both IF, ELSE statements have the same code. Something missing?

Comment: Sending mail is not the concern. It is expected to send the mail on completion of all the database.

Comment: try to use try catch block, also you have to add model and msdb in not in clause

Comment: @yatin parab, the code is not failing anywhere.

Comment: The only obvious possibility (to me, from the minimal code that you're showing us) is that multiple databases were offline at the time and this code isn't run by a high privilege user (and so rows for those databases wouldn't show up in `sys.databases`).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, The database backup process runs for 8 to 10 hours. It was running fine for past 2 weeks. The backup completed for first 9 DBs alphabetically (as it is ORDER BY NAME). And according to my shown code the OFFLINE dbs still get stored in the cursor. My Job is running with the ID having SYSADMIN access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Cursor type to `LOCAL STATIC` resolved my issue.

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC
```